# Xcode Compile error on CGPoint extension when archiving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I have the following piece of code in a framework that is used on iOS and WatchOS:

```
public extension CGPoint {
    static func * (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: Double) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: lhs.x * rhs, y: lhs.y * rhs)
    }
}
```

This works fine when building my iOS/WatchOS app for the simulator or device, in Xcode.

However when archiving the iOS app (with embedded WatchOS app) I get the following error when it's building.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Float'
```

on the part `lhs.x * rhs`

I don't understand what's going on as `CGPoint` only contains `Double` values.

Running Xcode 14.3 and building for WatchOS 9.

Comment: What happens if you change `Double` to `CGFloat`?

Comment: Then I get 'Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'Float''

Comment: In the file that you have this extentions what modules do you import?

Comment: Also check that are the architectures value in the build settings, it is possible that for release you have an 32bit architecture(like armv7) and in that architecture the CGFloat is defined as Float, if you removed it it will compile.

Comment: The thing is, in the code CoreGraphics, CGPoint is defined as containing 2 Double's, not CGFloats

Comment: While the decomentation shows 2 Double's if you check the header where the CGPoint is defined (CGGeometry.h) you will see that x & y are of type CGFloat. CGFloat when targeting a 32bit architecture is Float.

Comment: When you click on CGPoint in an Xcode project it sends you to "CFCGTypes.h" containing a definition with 2 Double's

Comment: You need to display the original source of the file CFCGTypes.h, see https://ibb.co/PYykrk4

Comment: So @JorisMans was the provided anwser a explaination of the problem you faced?